Python : Merge two dataframes based on created time
I have two dfs, two df's has be to be merged by class and joining dates. Please check the below df's
df1


class      teacher  age instructor_joining_date
   A        mark    50  2024-01-20 07:18:29.599
   A        john    45  2024-05-08 05:31:21.379


df2


class   count   student_joining_date
A          1    2024-05-17 01:05:58.072
A         50    2024-04-10 10:39:06.608
A         75    2024-04-05 09:49:07.246


Final output df

class   count   student_joining_date      teacher   age
A         1    2024-05-17 01:05:58.072    john       45
A        50    2024-04-10 10:39:06.608    mark       50
A        75    2024-04-05 09:49:07.246    mark       50


For df2 we have merge df1 by class and joining dates
Edit:
Yes if student_joining_date and instructor_joining_date is different. If student_joining_date is greater than instructor_joining_date then that teacher will be mapped here

Add some more details as we cannot understand how you got the final output df since instructor and student joining dates are different

Yes if student_joining_date and instructor_joining_date is different.
If student_joining_date is greater than instructor_joining_date then that teacher will be mapped

You have to use a merge_asof, then restore the original order with reindex:
df1['instructor_joining_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['instructor_joining_date'])
df2['student_joining_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['student_joining_date'])

out = (pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values(by='student_joining_date').reset_index(),
                     df1.sort_values(by='instructor_joining_date'),
                     left_on='student_joining_date',
                     right_on='instructor_joining_date',
                     by='class')
         .set_index('index').reindex(df2.index)
         .drop(columns='instructor_joining_date')
      )

Output:
  class  count    student_joining_date teacher  age
0     A      1 2024-05-17 01:05:58.072    john   45
1     A     50 2024-04-10 10:39:06.608    mark   50
2     A     75 2024-04-05 09:49:07.246    mark   50

Intermediate before dropping the instructor_joining_date column:
  class  count    student_joining_date teacher  age instructor_joining_date
0     A      1 2024-05-17 01:05:58.072    john   45 2024-05-08 05:31:21.379
1     A     50 2024-04-10 10:39:06.608    mark   50 2024-01-20 07:18:29.599
2     A     75 2024-04-05 09:49:07.246    mark   50 2024-01-20 07:18:29.599

